# Commented code in Wordpress template?

Tags: templates

I have a wordpress site that has to integrate with a .NET platform for a client. I simply need to add two commented out pieces of HTML for it to work on the .NET platform end (not our system).

Wordpress keeps stripping it out of the custom template, though. Is there a way around this?

Note: This is not done in the backend editor. This is directly in the template php file that I'm placing these two commented lines of code.

Also note: I already tried Linklays function to modify tinymce to see if that would be a solution, but again this isn't using tinymce since it's hard-coded into the template.

Edit: Template Code:
[image]

Comment: Please show some code (limited to the problem). Just from the text I don't really have an idea what you're currently doing.

Comment: `
   <div class="container">
    <div class="primary-content">
     <?php the_content(); ?>
     
     <h2><!--WebLink:ContentTitle--></h2>
       
       <!--WebLink:BodyContent1--> 
    </div>
   </div>
`
the commented out lines do not show, no matter what I do.

Comment: When you say the template PHP, how are you editing the template PHP? Is this the template file on the server? Are you making the changes then FTP'ing them up? Or are you using one of those dangerous plugins that let you put PHP directly into the database and run it? It's not clear, screenshots would be helpful!

Comment: Edited to include a screenshot of the template file with the commented code. The h2 shows up empty, the commented code doesn't show on inspect. I've tried doing this multiple ways and just haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: How should WordPress/PHP know, what `<!--WebLink:ContentTitle-->` means?

Comment: It's not, it doesn't need to. It just needs to show that the commented out code exists when viewing the source, and it doesn't. It strips it.

Comment: A possibility to look into ... There may be a post-processing filter in your Wordpress hosting setup. This could be by your hosting provider, or by a plug-in. One of our providers does this with an Apache/.htaccess add-on and it happens after the Wordpress processing is done.

Comment: For future reference, post code as code. When you post it as an image, it's not selectable and no one is going to retype to include in an answer. The easier you make it for people to answer, the better answers you'll get for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, autoptimize strikes again.